# Selenium-WebDriver won't work with proxy

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, rubygems, selenium-webdriver

I have a couple of dev machines.  One works, the other doesn't.

Setup that doesn't work:

Host: quad
Firefox: 13.0.1
Ubuntu: 12.04 Desktop
Ruby: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)
RubyGems: 1.8.15
Selenium-WebDriver: 2.24.0
Proxy: 192.168.1.70:8118

Setup that does work:

Host: dev
Firefox: 13.0
Ubuntu: 12.04 Desktop
Ruby: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)
RubyGems: 1.8.24
Selenium-WebDriver: 2.22.2
Proxy: 127.0.0.1:8118

In the setup that doesn't work (host quad) Firefox will pop up but then log an error regarding an unexpected 503 response (I use Privoxy and on the machine that doesn't work I make the proxy available to the whole LAN, so my proxy is 192.168.1.70:8118).

Firefox opens and doesn't close when the Ruby script crashes.  So I've been able to use that Firefox instance to surf the internet.  That works fine.  So Firefox is able to start up and go through Privoxy just fine.  The Privoxy 503 page never shows up on the Firefox I'm seeing pop up only in the logs.

I've also tried this script (on host quad) with Chrome.  Same error in the logs but Chrome never pops up a window for me.  I assume this is due to the difference in the way proxies are handled by the 2 browsers.

On host dev, this script works fine.  The script works without error when the proxy is 127.0.0.1:8118 (it's local Privoxy).  Since the Privoxy on host quad is available to the whole LAN I changed the proxy setting on host dev to 192.168.1.70:8118.  Once I did this I ran the script on host dev and got the Privoxy error in the terminal but Firefox opened and executed the rest of the script as if the error never happened.

My assumption is that this is a subtle difference in my setup that is causing issues.  But I don't know if it is Firefox 13.0.1. vs 13.0 or my version of RubyGems or my version of Selenium-WebDriver.

I figure that ideally I should have the same setup on both machines.  But which setup is better?  I'd prefer to be able to work with the latest Firefox just because I get sick of telling the Update Manager in Ubuntu to not execute all the Firefox updates every day.  And when I run apt-get update/upgrade I don't want to have to manually remove all of the Firefox updates.  That said, if the best setup is to use Firefox 10, Ruby 1.8.7, RubyGems ... then I'll just go setup some VM that I don't bother running apt-get update/upgrade on so I have a more stable environment.

Thanks

Comment: Both systems are running privoxy 3.0.19 and I've tried changing the privoxy to work on 127.0.0.1.  Still no go.  The code is bombing on this line `b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile` and using a begin/end statement to trap it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a forward setting in Privoxy.  I had to setup forwarding for 127.*.*.*/ in /etc/privoxy/config.  I had already setup forwarding for 192.168.*.*/ and thought that was fine since the Proxy IP was 192.168.1.70 but it wasn't good enough.